Qualys while using https://qualysapi.qg3.apps.qualys.com/qps/rest/3.0/create/was/webapp <errorMessage>Unknown field type: defaultTags</errorMessage>
In Postman POST: https://qualysapi.qg3.apps.qualys.com/qps/rest/3.0/create/was/webapp
This is working:
{

"ServiceRequest": {

    "data": {

        "WebApp": {

            "name": "Dev-DevSecOps",

            "url": "https://example.com/"

        }

    }

}

}

 

But not able to set apply exiting Tags :
{

"ServiceRequest": {

    "data": {

        "WebApp": {

            "name": "DevSecOps",

            "defaultTags": {            // Container for default tags

                "set": {                   // Set of tags

                    "TagSimple": [           // List of TagSimple objects

                        {

                            "id": XXXXX       // ID of the first tag

                        }

                    ]

                }

            },

            "url": "https://example.com/"

        }

    }

}

}

Getting Error:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://qualysapi.qg3.apps.qualys.com/qps/xsd/3.0/was/webapp.xsd">
    <responseCode>INVALID_REQUEST</responseCode>
    <responseErrorDetails>
        <errorMessage>Unknown field type: defaultTags</errorMessage>
    </responseErrorDetails>
</ServiceResponse>

Similarly other configurations are having same issue:
"crawlScope": {
                   "includeSubdomains": "true",
                  "includeHttps": "true"
               },
              "profile": {
                  "id": "123"
              },
               "scannerAppliance": {
                   "type": "INTERNAL",
                   "name": "APP101"
               },
               "webAppAuthRecord": {
                   "isDefault": "true",
                   "name": "webAppAuthRecord_name"
               }

So any idea what are correct field type as this are same in XML so what should be in JSON?

any help in this is very much Appreciated
